# How do I fix JMeterPluginsCMD "Missing plugin type specification" error

Tags: windows, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to use the JMeterPluginsCMD on Windows to generate load test result graphs after a JMeter run.  I installed the plugin manually because I can't use the JMeter Plugins Manager.  (I don't have the network information I need to configure it).  When I run a simple command `.\JMeterPluginsCMD.bat`, I get an error message.  What can I do about this error message?

Here's the error message `ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing plugin type specification`

Here's the full error output:

```
~\Desktop\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin> .\JMeterPluginsCMD.bat
2019-08-12 12:10:29,564 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to: ISO-8859-1
2019-08-12 12:10:29,571 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
2019-08-12 12:10:29,572 INFO k.a.j.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
2019-08-12 12:10:29,574 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2019-08-12 12:10:29,578 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading user properties from: C:\Path\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\user.properties
2019-08-12 12:10:29,582 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading system properties from: C:\Path\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\system.properties
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing plugin type specification
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: C:\Path\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing plugin type specification
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.checkParams(PluginsCMDWorker.java:78)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.doJob(PluginsCMDWorker.java:104)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:255)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
~\Desktop\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin>
```

Comment: See https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks, that did it.  The examples in that link use the ResponseTimesOverTime plugin-type.  I didn't see that that has to be installed separately.  I downloaded the JAR files from here https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-graphs-basic and copied them to my JMeter/ext folder, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [plugin-type parameter](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), example:

> ```
> JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png test.png --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600
> ```

Your plugin jar should be available in lib/ext folder

> Make note that you need to install corresponding plugins set to have Extras plugins available in CMD.